# Print twice console message

Tags: java, log4j

I created this Java code to configure Log4J

```
public class LogMessages
{
    private final Logger log;

    public LogMessages(Configuration cv)
    {
        log = Logger.getLogger(LogMessages.class);

        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
        // configure the appender
        console.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n"));   // Set output format for the console messages

        String consoleLoggingLevel = cv.getConsoleLoggingLevel();

        if ("DEBUG".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        }
        else if ("INFO".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
        }
        else if ("WARN".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.WARN);
        }
        else if ("ERROR".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.ERROR);
        }
        else if ("FATAL".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
        }
        else if ("OFF".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleLoggingLevel))
        {
            console.setThreshold(Level.OFF);
        }

        console.activateOptions();

        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

        DailyRollingFileAppender fa = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("log" + File.separator + "messages.log");
        fa.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n"));    // Set output format for the file logging

        String fileLoggingLevel = cv.getFileLoggingLevel();

        if ("DEBUG".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        }
        else if ("INFO".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
        }
        else if ("WARN".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.WARN);
        }
        else if ("ERROR".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.ERROR);
        }
        else if ("FATAL".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
        }
        else if ("OFF".equalsIgnoreCase(fileLoggingLevel))
        {
            fa.setThreshold(Level.OFF);
        }

        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();

        // add appender to any Logger
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa);
    }
```

But for some reason Console message is printed twice. Can you help me to solve this issue?

I suppose that configuration is not correct but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Do you get console output without the console appender?

Comment: Yes, I removed `fa.setAppend(true);` but I still see messages twice.

Comment: Not that one.  Comment out this call:  `Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);`

Comment: fa.setAppend(true) just means that the log file is not truncated when the program starts. It's not where you should watch

Comment: I removed `Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);` Now the messages are not printed.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the same logging message two or more times, that's because you have two or more loggers that write to the same appender. Either you disable additivity of the child logger or you identify the loggers and remove the unwanted appenders.

To identify the loggers you can either print the logger name in the message (`%c`), or set a breakpoint in the log4j code.

Comment: Can you show me how I have to edit the code, please?

Comment: Add a `[%c]` to your console layout and post the program output somewhere

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `org.apache.log4j.Category#addAppender` and look at the top frames. Or otherwise just `log.setAdditivity(false)` in the code you posted

Comment: What do you mean? I use Netbeans? By the way this is a OSGI application and I can't test it into IDE. I start the application on a OSGI framework.

Comment: Every JVM can start with a debugger... Anyway, turning off additivity should fix the double message, since you are having troubles debugging your application and can't give us a reproducible test program

Comment: Show what? Did you test your program with log.setAdditivity(false) ?

Comment: Yes, I added `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.DX_57.osgi.ts.impl.LogMessages).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`

Comment: Do you actually log twice? I can't help you further if you don't set a breakpoint

Comment: Can you give me more information how i have to set the breakpoint?

Comment: If you use an IDE there's a debug button. If you use the command line or anyway a CLI tool, there's the -Xdebug option